# Python: how to check if an element is not in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a newbie in python & using python 3.4.3 in PyCharm in windows. Suppose that i have a list in python in which (0,2,4)th elements are names(string) and (1,3,5)th elements are theirs' rolls(int)

```
list = ['a',12,'b',16,'c',20]
```

if i want to prompt the user to enter a roll number, then delete the roll and the previous string with:

```
delRoll = list.index(int(input("Delete roll no: ")))
del (list[delRoll - 1: delRoll + 1])
```

i tested it worked fine(e.g.deleted the name and roll) if the user enters the numbers enlisted in the `list` , But how to find if the users hasn't entered a roll  that is not enlisted in the `list`  & give him/her a error message?

Comment: `if x not in y`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Find in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list)

Comment: @Ashish Disagree, this is specifically, check if an item is "not" in a list. It is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406130/check-if-something-is-not-in-a-list-in-python however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple `if-else` pair for this:

```
l = ['a',12,'b',16,'c',20]
roll = int(input())
if roll in l:
    del (l[l.index(roll) - 1: l.index(roll) + 1])
    print("Succes! Your list is ",l)
else:
    print("Number not in list.")
```

If the number one enters is `12`, the result is `Succes! Your list is  ['b', 16, 'c', 20]`.

As *@Rawing* pointed out in the comments, this method has too much linear time complexity, and thus I recommend this method:

```
l = ['a',12,'b',16,'c',20]
roll = int(input())
i = 0
try:
    i = l.index(roll)
except ValueError:
    print("The given number is not in the list.")
else:
    del(l[i-1:i+1])
    print("Succes, your list is: ",l)
```

---

*Quick note: You should not use `list` as a variable name, because it is the keyword for a list (array).*

Comment: `if roll in l` has a linear time complexity, as does `l.index(...)`. Your code has 3 occurences of linear complexity, with no good reason. Using a `try: ... except:` like in [Zed Evan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44108353/1222951) would be a better way to do this.

Comment: @Rawing fixed now.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder , thanks a lot !! it worked.... i'm totally new in python, so didn't know about that `try`  `except` method ....  :-)
One more ques.: why did you initialize `i = 0 ' first ??

Comment: Because if I wouldn't have initialised it, I couldn't have used it in the `else` clause: `del(l[i-1:i+1])`, because it would be declared locally in the `try` statement, which would be useless since it would be moved outside of its usage scope. Basically, I have declared it globally to be able to use it everywhere in the program after its initialization

Answer (score 2):

```
list = ['a',4,'b',2]

try:
    b=a.index('a')
except ValueError:
    "Throw Error"
else:
    "Do something with the value"
```

Comment: ummm... what's b and a here in your `try`  segment,please?? :-)

Comment: we try to get an index of a value , if we do get 1 we will go to the else block, but if he does not exist , Python will throw an error , called ValueError , so we need to catch it and do something , in your case is to return it . b is a var only for checking his not infecting the code