# basic user log in/pw code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just started learning python a couple days ago and have been trying to use what code I know to practice a basic code of asking for a user name and password from a list. I know there are far better/cleaner/matching user to password inputs but I'm just playing with what I know at this point.

```
users = ['Jon','Joe', 'Jole']

user_input = input('Username: ')

while user_input != users:
    user_redo = input("I'm sorry but we dont recognize you. Please try another username: ")
```

**this is where my problem is. Is there a simple way of breaking the loop if the user enters a matching username from the list?**

```
passwords = ['donkey808','Hanna5006']
password = input('Password: ')
```

**I guess the same question would apply to the password entry as well**

```
while password != passwords:
    pw_redo = input(f'Please enter correct password for user {user_input}: ')
else:
    print(f'Access Granted {user_input}')
```

Comment: change `while user_input != users:` to `while user_input not in users:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if something is not in a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406130/check-if-something-is-not-in-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it like this.

```
users = ["Jon","Joe", "Jole"]
while 0 < 1 :
  user_input = input('Username: ')
  if user_input not in users:
      print("I'm sorry but we dont recognize you. Please try another username: ")
  elif user_input in users:
    break
```

Comment: Can I ask what is the significance of using the 0<1 ? Does it give the while function something to check against?

Comment: it's a True statement to continue the loop there are many other ways to do so but this one is simple and easy. nothing else :)

Comment: Thank you Ali. Yes, I have yet to reach that point in my lesson. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `while user_input not in users:`

`not in` checks if `user_input` is literally *not in* `users`

It might also be better to do `if user_input not in users:`, I don't see the point of a while.

Comment: If your answer basically repeats what has been mentioned in the comments (and not even by yourself), it should probably be submitted as Community Wiki entry.

Comment: @OndrejK. I was typing my answer here while they were talking. The answer is kind of obvious in this case, i was typing out my answer, I didn't see their answer

Comment: Doesn't really look like 7 minutes worth of typing? See, how this could be just pointed out as a suggestion though?

Comment: Thank you Sheshank. I was using 'while' because the source I'm using to self study python hasnt gotten to the 'not in' function. I was just poking around and jumping ahead. But the 'not in' makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @JonahMolina if it helped remember to upvote and mark as correct answer :)

Comment: @SheshankS. Ok so I tried using the 'if user_input not in' and it works for the first attempt, but with a second attempt, itll proceed to the password step if the user_input was correct or not. That is why I was using the 'while' as a check to loop until the user entered a matching username from the list

Comment: @JonahMolina can you make a repl.it for this? I canhelp you better there

Comment: It would actually be better to make a new question

Comment: @SheshankS. Sorry about that. I wasnt getting a message if it registered my click or not so I clicked it a bunch of times hoping that it would go through / land on accept