# Remove all elements from a list called friends, whose names do not end in a vowel

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I would like to use list comprehension. Have tried multiple iterations, just current one shown.

```
friends = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Derek']

cons_ends = [i for i in friends if i[-1] != ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")]

print(cons_ends)

['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Derek']
```

Comment: Use `if i[-1] not in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")`  instead. (or better yet: `if i[-1] not in "aeiou"`)

Comment: See [Check if something is (not) in a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10406130/15497888) and [Python Membership Operators Example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/membership_operators_example.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This should work->

```
friends = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Derek']
friends = [x for x in friends if x[-1].lower() in ['a','e','i','o','u']]
print(friends)
```

Output ->

```
['Alice', 'Charlie']
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes, it is removing those elements whose names do not end in a vowel.