# Python list while loop check

Tags: python

my aim is to run the while loop until the user inputs a option that is in my list. If they do the while loop should end.

```
exchangeCurrency = input("what currency would you like to convert to: ").upper()

myList = ["USD", "ERU", "BRL", "JPY", "TRY"]

while exchangeCurrency != myList:
    print("this is not a valid inpit")
    continue
else:
    break
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if something is (not) in a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406130/check-if-something-is-not-in-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while True:
    exchangeCurrency = input("what currency would you like to convert to: ").upper()
    if exchangeCurrency in myList:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the code:

```py
myList = ["USD", "ERU", "BRL", "JPY", "TRY"]

userInput = input("Enter a currency: ").upper()
while userInput not in myList:
    print("Currency not found")
    userInput = input("Enter a currency: ").upper()
```

Comment: Can save two lines with an assignment expression: `while (userInput := input("Enter a currency: ").upper()) not in myList:`

Comment: @flakes I do know this is a valid option but it is usually better to not give a one-linear to a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = ["USD", "ERU", "BRL", "JPY", "TRY"]
while (exchangeCurrency := input("what currency would you like to convert to: ").upper()) not in myList:
    print("Error: currency not found")
```

Answer (score -1):

a simple solution that may work

```
isTrue = True

while isTrue:
 if exchangeCurrency != myList:
   print("try again. Invalid currency")
 else:
   print("this currency is on the list")
   isTrue = False
```